# Removing Non Ssl Content From Google Cache

Tags: google

We had switched our e-commerce site to HTTPS. Currently the site is working properly. I made redirect from http to https via apache. According to Webmaster tool, all organic visitors is coming from new result. But there is 140k indexed pages non ssl version of site.

How can I delete properly http version of indexed pages from google cache?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select https version in your webmaster tools account
2. Create new sitemap with https version of the files
3. Robots.txt the old files
4. Change all links in your website with https
5. Change all old external links with https vertion where is posible
6. [https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/make-sure-google-can-index-and-serve.html)
7. Wait :(